# Shebang directing to specific virtualenv - is it a good idea?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a script for which I must have a specific virtualenv on.

Running the script with `#!/usr/bin/env python / python3 / python3.6` will not cut it if the virtualenv is not on when the script runs, so I have done something like this:

```
#!/home/bla/bla2/bla3/venv/bin/python
import virtualenv stuff...
```

I assume that

1. virtualenv will be installed beforehand
2. the script / dir / venv will stay in the exact same place

Given those 2 assumptions, is this a good idea? If not, what would be better? I'm reluctant to having a wrapper bash script that would turn on the venv and then call my script

Comment: Not assuming would be better? If the script is just for you, then it's fine; leave a comment to change the path. Otherwise.... check if env is installed, install if not, and so on...

Comment: Honestly, it is ugly. But if you really cannot have a wrapper bash script, and really can ensure those two conditions, it should be fine.

Comment: It's going to be a "Works on my machine!" solution.

Comment: Not sure ugly and "works on my machine" solution are a bad thing given this is exactly what I want. [shrug :-)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, this is how the console scripts for entry points are generated. Of course there are the limitations that files and directories can not be renamed, etc. but well that is quite obvious.

For example here is the content of the `pip` script in a freshly created virtual environment:

```
/tmp/tmp.cqz22j4Vg7$ cat .venv/bin/pip
```

```
#!/tmp/tmp.cqz22j4Vg7/.venv/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

I believe the shebang in the scripts is an absolute path exactly so that they can be called without having to activate the virtual environment.

A common practice is to keep such a virtual environment around and add a symbolic link to a particular script in a directory listed in `PATH`. For example, one could install *tox* in a virtual environment and make it available from anywhere:

```
ln -s '/path/to/venv/bin/tox' "${HOME}/.local/bin/tox"
```

From Python's *venv* documentation:

> There should be no need in other circumstances to activate a virtual environment; scripts installed into virtual environments have a “shebang” line which points to the virtual environment’s Python interpreter.

-- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=shebang

Answer (score 7):

You should create a script that builds the venv and then runs the script inside it. Hardcoding the path to the venv python is a terrible idea, because if you change your username, PC, etc. or give someone else the code (or make it open source) it will fail.

Comment: I agree my solution isn't generic, but aside from that (as I said in my assumptions) is there an inherent flaw in this? It won't go open source and won't be used by other machine / user. I mean, why use a wrapper? It also assumes stuff about the virtualenv (like path...) so how is it better?

Comment: @CIsForCookies A shell script doesn't have to assume anything - it can locate itself on disk, and use either dedicated venv commands or simple globbing to setup the venv. On the other hand, what happens if your disk dies, and you have to reinstall everything from backups - you might change your username, or just put the project in a different folder? The loss in that case exceeds the effort of making a script.